# Chrome Extension: content_scripts matches for custom new tab page

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a custom new tab page for Chrome. I have it in my manifest.json so that: `"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "home.html"
  }`
It won't, however, load the scripts that I load in my home.html. I found out that you need to use content_scripts, so now I also have
`"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [""],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "js": ["logic.js", "macros.js"]
    }
  ]`
What do I put in the "matches"? It doesn't allow "home.html" or "chrome://newtab".

Comment: Can we see your html, and you can write the JS in the HTML file. The reason chrome://newtab doesn't work is because contentscripts doesn't support that scheme for matching

Comment: Yea, the code is [link](http://pastebin.com/PKyKZ1JR) I know I can just put all the js and css into the html, but it'd be a lot cleaner to have them separate if possible

Comment: I figured it out! It wasn't because of content_scripts, I can eliminate that completely from my manifest.json. It was because I had the non-local javascript files for angular and jquery. I instead downloaded those two javascript files and included them, and it worked.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it!

Comment: Content scripts can't be injected into `chrome-extension://` pages